# Subquery returned more than 1 value - Multuple error message

Tags: sql

I have this code below, I got this error: Subquery returned more than 1 value .. As you can see, I am using a subquery that cause this problem.

What to do? Please help me to fix this problem.

```
    SELECT 
    [MAGASIN] = ET2.ET_LIBELLE ,
    [CA]= sum(GL_MONTANTTTC),
    [NBR TICKET] = count(distinct GL_NUMERO),

    (SELECT
    [NBR TICKET] = count(distinct GL_NUMERO)

    FROM GCLIGNEARTDIM 

LEFT OUTER JOIN ETABLISS ET2 ON GL_ETABLISSEMENT=ET2.ET_ETABLISSEMENT 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN COMMERCIAL GCL3 ON GL_REPRESENTANT=GCL3.GCL_COMMERCIAL 
    WHERE (GL_DATEPIECE >= '20190228 00:00:00' AND GL_DATEPIECE < '20190301 00:00:00' 
    AND (GCL3.GCL_LIBELLE='vendeur x'))
    AND GL_ETABLISSEMENT in ('W01','W05','F10')

    GROUP BY
    ET2.ET_LIBELLE

    )AS 'VENDEUR X'

    FROM GCLIGNEARTDIM 

LEFT OUTER JOIN ETABLISS ET2 ON GL_ETABLISSEMENT=ET2.ET_ETABLISSEMENT  
    LEFT OUTER JOIN COMMERCIAL GCL3 ON GL_REPRESENTANT=GCL3.GCL_COMMERCIAL 


    WHERE (GL_DATEPIECE >= '20190228 00:00:00' AND GL_DATEPIECE < '20190301 00:00:00'
    AND GL_ETABLISSEMENT in ('W01','W05','F10')

    GROUP BY
    ET2.ET_LIBELLE

    ORDER BY
    ET2.ET_LIBELLE
```

Comment: Have no GROUP BY in the sub-query. Instead make the sub-query correlated. (I.e. condition referencing main query column.)

Comment: which part gives the error?

Comment: When i'v delete the group by from the subquery, the subquery column ('VENDEUR X') returns the same value.

Answer (score 0):

Your code could use a little reformatting to help with readability. You are more likely to get a quality answer if folks can quickly and easily digest your question and your code. Also, you had an extra open parenthesis in your WHERE clause on the outer query.

When using a sub query you should avoid using the same table aliases as the outer query. Use unique aliases.

The issue you are experiencing is being caused by the sub query you have producing the column VENDEUR X. For a sub query to work it needs to only return one row when executed. In your case it is returning multiple rows which is throwing the error message.

To troubleshoot the issue run the sub query independently and inspect the data being returned. You are grouping on column ET2.ET_LIBELLE which has multiple values. Based on what I guess you are trying to do, you should add ET2.ET_LIBELLE to the WHERE clause. See my example below.

```
SELECT 
    [MAGASIN] = ET2.ET_LIBELLE,
    [CA]= SUM(GL_MONTANTTTC),
    [NBR TICKET] = COUNT(DISTINCT GL_NUMERO),
    (
        SELECT [NBR TICKET] = COUNT(DISTINCT GL_NUMERO) 
        FROM 
            GCLIGNEARTDIM 
            LEFT OUTER JOIN ETABLISS ETI ON GL_ETABLISSEMENT=ETI.ET_ETABLISSEMENT 
            LEFT OUTER JOIN COMMERCIAL GCLI ON GL_REPRESENTANT=GCLI.GCL_COMMERCIAL 
        WHERE 
            (
                GL_DATEPIECE >= '20190228 00:00:00' 
                AND GL_DATEPIECE < '20190301 00:00:00' 
                AND (GCL3.GCL_LIBELLE='vendeur x')
            )
            AND GL_ETABLISSEMENT IN ('W01','W05','F10')
            AND ETI.ET_LIBELLE = ET2.ET_LIBELLE
    ) AS 'VENDEUR X'
FROM 
    GCLIGNEARTDIM 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ETABLISS ET2 ON GL_ETABLISSEMENT=ET2.ET_ETABLISSEMENT  
    LEFT OUTER JOIN COMMERCIAL GCL3 ON GL_REPRESENTANT=GCL3.GCL_COMMERCIAL
WHERE 
    GL_DATEPIECE >= '20190228 00:00:00' 
    AND GL_DATEPIECE < '20190301 00:00:00' 
    AND GL_ETABLISSEMENT IN ('W01','W05','F10')
GROUP BY
    ET2.ET_LIBELLE
ORDER BY
    ET2.ET_LIBELLE
```

Comment: Thank you so much. u saved my time !! i really understand my mistake

Comment: No problem. If this completely answers your question please mark it as correct.

Comment: One last question please, i want to store the subquery in a variable or something, so i can call it after. how to do ?

Comment: That would be an entirely different question. You should make a new post for it.